# How to calculate the Output Impedance of RoT1?

Tags: transistors, bjt, impedance, small-signal

[image: Image with the transistor]

I am a student, and I want to calculate the small-signal analysis, but I don't really know what's the formula of RoT1 (being a degenerated common base with RoT1 in the collector).

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: You pretty much must *first* be able to calculate the DC quiescent point. Have you got that? Or a process to get it?

Comment: Hi! I have calculated the DC bias. Did the closed loop schema but I can't figure out the RoT1 formula (which will be included in calculating the Stabilization Factor). Can you help me out with the formula?

Comment: @EngineerMan I think the point is for you to show us what you have tried, so that people can pinpoint the errors, or at least give you hints on how to continue and from where. But if you don't show anything, how can anyone read your mind?

Comment: What is "RoT1"?